# Advanced Search Filter

Tags: query, plugin-smartmap

I am trying to complete an advanced search query with Smart Map, but I can't seem to quite get it. I tried to merge several URL parameters, and they seem to work fine except when it comes down to Smart Map's query.

I followed along with the example [here](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/sorting-entries-by-closest-locations/), but it's not fully rendering correctly. The Smart Map field is named `jobAddress`, in the section called `jobListings`.

Can anyone take a peek at my code and perhaps point out what I am doing wrong? Disclaimer... I am extremely new to Craft. I appreciate your help and guidance!

```html
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block main %}

    {# Set variables for each possible param: #}
    {% set state = craft.app.request.getParam('state') %}
    {% set trucktype = craft.app.request.getParam('trucktype') %}
    {% set city = craft.app.request.getParam('city') %}
    {% set target = craft.app.request.getParam('zip') %}
    {% set range = craft.app.request.getParam('range') %}

    {# Here we set the criteria and combine all the parameter variables #}
    {% set criteria = {
        section: 'jobListings',
        state: state,
        truckType: trucktype,
        city: city,
        jobAddress:{
            zip:target
        }
    } %}

    {# Pass the criteria object to the query builder: #}
    {% set query = craft.entries(criteria) %}

    {% if target is not empty and range is not empty %}
        {% set query = query|merge({
            jobAddress:{
                range: range
            }
        }) %}
    {% endif %}

    {# We build the map location based on criteria #}
    <div class="container-fluid" id="map">
        <div class="row bg-secondary">
            <div class="col-sm-12 p-0">
                {% set locations = query %}
                {% set options = {
                    height:400,
                    zoom: 5,
                    'markerInfo': 'searchjobs/infoBubble',
                    markerOptions: {
                        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
                    }
                } %}
                {{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {# DISPLAY Search Results #}
    <div class="container-fluid pt-5 pb-1 jobs-index">
        <h1 class="text-center">Search Results</h1>
        {# Set up pagination, and let it grab the current page's results: #}
        {% paginate query as pageInfo, results %}

        {% for result in results %}
            <div class="row p-4">
                <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 bg-light p-2">
                    <h3 class="job-header">{{ result.title }}</h3>
                    <p><strong><em>Truck:</em></strong> {{ result.truckType }}</p>
                    <p><strong><em>State</em></strong>{{ result.state}}</p>
                    <p><strong><em>City:</em></strong> {{ result.city}}</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-details" href="/jobs/{{result.slug}}">Get More Details &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> </a>
                    <p class="pt-2"><strong>Benefits: </strong>
                        {% for option in result.jobBenefits %}
                            {{ option.value }}
                            {# Value: {{ option }} or {{ option.value }} #}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                    {# Show the Radius #}
                    <p><strong>{{ result.jobAddress.distance | number_format(1) }} miles away</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="search-again">
            <h3 class="text-center">Didn't find what you're looking for?</h3>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success search-again-btn" href="/jobs">Search Again</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is a live preview of the [current site...](https://conversionia.frb.io/jobs)

Answer (score 1):

Author of Smart Map here... I can't tell exactly what question you are asking, so I'll give an answer based on my understanding of the problem.

It looks like your biggest problem is here:

```
    {% set criteria = {
        section: 'jobListings',
        state: state,
        truckType: trucktype,
        city: city,
        jobAddress: {
            zip: target
        }
    } %}
```

If you are trying to filter by the `state`, `city`, and `zip` of the **jobAddress** field, then those will need to be contained in a `filter` parameter...

```
    {% set criteria = {
        section: 'jobListings',
        truckType: trucktype,
        jobAddress: {
            filter: {
                state: state,
                city: city,
                zip: target
            }
        }
    } %}
```

Check out the docs on [Filtering entries by subfield value](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/filtering-entries-by-subfield-value/) for more information. Hope that helps!